# Frontmatter in Padrino

Tags: padrino, middleman

In Middleman, there is a feature called [frontmatter](http://middlemanapp.com/frontmatter/). Basically, you can put some YAML in front of your view and access it in the view and the layout like this:

```
---
my_list:
  - one
  - two
  - three
---

<h1>List</h1>
<ol>
  <% current_page.data.my_list.each do |f| %>
  <li><%= f %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Is there a similar thing in Padrino?

Answer (score 0):

Such feature does not come with padrino, where you usually would let these values be filled by your controllers.

Depending on your use case, you might use the content_for output helper (http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/application-helpers).

This might help if e.g. want to define the title (as in html/head/title) -- which is usually set by the layout template -- in the "nested" template of your page.